# Nginx routing not working when refresh page or when I go directly to the page

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I'm running Docker Containers with a Vue.js front and a Node.js+Express.js backend and managing the routes using Nginx.

When I access the route https://equilibrista.app/ and click the link inside the page to go to https://equilibrista.app/exams it works fine, but I got an error when I directly goes to this page (and a Express error shows up `Cannot GET /exams`).

[image: link to /exams page]

Why is this happening? It looks like an Nginx redirect error, but I couldn't find anything wrong on nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name equilibrista.app www.equilibrista.app;

  location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    allow all;
    root /var/www/html;
  }

  location / {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name equilibrista.app www.equilibrista.app;

  server_tokens off;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/equilibrista.app/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/equilibrista.app/privkey.pem;

  ssl_buffer_size 8k;

  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

  ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://api:3000/;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://front:8888;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way we got it to work with a Vue app was following.

1) First you have a location that capture all the physical files and paths that exists.

2) Secondly you redirect any other request to the main application file, for Vue it is index.html.

So your location configuration should look like this:

```
location /api/ { 
    proxy_pass http://api:3000/; 
} 

location ~* \/(index\.html|favicon\.ico|styles\.css|styles\.min\.css|css\/.*|js\/.*|images\/.*) {
    proxy_pass http://front:8888;
} 

location / { 
    rewrite / /index.html; 
    proxy_pass http://front:8888;
}
```

(updated to match question)

we have the static files on the nginx server, but it should work the same way with proxy_pass.

Comment: I had the same results in Vue.js as I had before, but the API stopped working.

Comment: you /api/ location must be listed before, the locations i mentioned.

Comment: I tried to use the nginx.conf like this:
```location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://api:3000/;
  }

  location ~* \/(index\.html|favicon\.ico|styles\.css|styles\.min\.css|css\/.*|js\/.*|images\/.*) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @front =404;
  }

  location / {
    autoindex off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @front;
  }

  location @front {
    proxy_pass http://front:8888;
  }```

Comment: I have updated my answer config. What you should do, is testing each location at a time. So first get /api/ working. Then the specific file location. and last the catch all location.

Comment: So which locations didn't work, neither 3 only 1? Go through the 3 locations and report which work and those that didn't. Im am unsure if you can make a `try_files` with a location to a proxy_pass. I would try setting the proxy_pass directly at the location with the physical files.